# Pushing tag in git gives error: size of file is over limit

Tags: git

I'm working with a remote repository that has some rather big files. However, I am able to commit, push and pull with no problem.

However, when I try to add an annotated tag

```
git tag -a v0.0.1 -m 'First tag, to a very beta version.'
```

and then push it to the repo, I get:

```
$ git push origin v0.0.1
Counting objects: 1, done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 181 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Size of file '...' in commit ... is over limit (20000000 bytes)
...
remote: Size of file '...' in commit ... is over limit (20000000 bytes)
remote: Size of file '...' in commit ... is over limit (20000000 bytes)
To https://....git
 ! [remote rejected] v0.0.1 -> v0.0.1 (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://....git'
```

Some more info:

1. The branch I'm working on doesn't have these big files anymore. These big files are still in the history, and in another branch, but not on recent commits.
2. The local repository is a --single-branch clone, with --depth=5, so those big files that are giving error should not be at all in this local repo.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are interesting clues in the output which tell us that it's the remote repository's hooks that are misbehaving.  (Which in turn means that unless you have direct access to that system, and can fuss with the hooks over there, you can't fix this yourself.  Of course if you have direct access to that system, you can just go set the tag there in the first place.)

Let's start with a brief review.  This:

> `remote: Size of file '...' in commit ... is over limit (20000000 bytes)`

comes from a pre-receive hook (or potentially, an update hook, but we see `pre-receive` in the `remote rejected` line).  These hooks are typically in place to stop people from accidentally adding commits with large binaries or database files or whatnot.  The code in the hook that finds these does a graph traversal using the proposed reference update (or creation), and in this case, it's clearly taking the *tag* create operation and traversing a bunch of existing commits, some of which have large files, hence spitting out the error messages and rejecting the push.

You mention that

> The branch I'm working on doesn't have these big files anymore. These big files are still in the history, and in another branch, but not on recent commits.

While the *branch* is not actually of interest—you're pushing a tag, not a branch, so the reference update the remote is getting is `refs/tags/v0.0.1`—we now know that there *are* large files in the repository (on the remote, though not locally due to the limited depth of the clone).

The other key clue here is this:

> ```
> Counting objects: 1, done.
> Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 181 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
> Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
> ```

Your push is sending one (1) object that is 181 bytes long and not delta-compressed against any other objects.  This is, of course, the annotated tag object, and clearly there are no 20-megabyte files here!  Thus, the remote *must* be finding them as a consequence of following the tag object's target (which would be the `HEAD` commit at the time you made the tag: this commit must already exist on the remote since your push is not sending it), and—incorrectly—concluding that some commit(s) already in the remote repository are therefore new and should be error-ed out.